# Using eledmac package to arrange footnotes by line number

Tags: footnotes, eledmac

I've got a question about formatting footnotes using eledmac. I'm trying to create a critical edition of a manuscript text using XeTeX, Memoir and `eledmac` and I would like the footnotes (`\Afootnote`) to be arranged according to the standard single column at the bottom of the page (`\footnormal{A}`). However, instead of listing the different footnotes belonging to the same line-number as separate individual row entries (with the repeated line-number in each instance), I'd like the footer to have ALL footnotes belonging to the same line to be listed as a single row entry, mutually separating them with an appropriate separator (semicolon or \hspace for instance)

As an example of what it currently resembles for the following text (following lineation) --

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[parapparatus]{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}


\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\protect
\noindent
{\edtext{lorem}{\Afootnote{loreim A, lorieem B}}\\
\edtext{ipsum}{\Afootnote{ipsium A}} dolor sit \edtext{amet}{\Afootnote{amit B}}\\
\edtext{consectetuer}{\Afootnote{consectetor A}} adipiscing elit\\
sed diam nonummy}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

FOOTER

```
 1 lorem ] loreim A, lorieem B
 2 ipsum ] ipsium A
 2 amet ] amit B
 3 consectetuer ] consectetor A
```

What I'd like to have is --

FOOTER

```
 1 lorem ] loreim A, lorieem B
 2 ipsum ] ipsium A  \hspace{5pt}  amet ] amit B
 3 consectetuer ] consectetor A
```

If anyone can help with this that would be super!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

I see three question in your post:

1. Don't repeat two time the same line number in note.
2. Have a special space or character in place of the second line number of the same line.
3. Place the critical notes of the same text line in the same notes' line, but not have a new notes line for each text line.

Actually, there is not way for the 3. problem. The only way is to have all notes in the same paragraph. Using `\footparagraph{A}` (see 4.2 of handbook).

For the first point, use `\numberonlyfirstinline`, eventually with `\numberonlyfirstintwolines` (the question is how to manage the case where there is a note on l. 2 and a note on l. 2-3. See 4.3.1).

For the second point (which is a consequence of the first), use `\symlinenum{<your symbol>}`, for example `\symlinenum{\hspace{1em}}`.

Comment: Thanks for that, I figured out using \numberonlyfirstinline and \symlinenum{\hspace{1em}}, but that still gives me a long list of very short footnotes per line and occupies quite a bit of the page. \footnoteparagraph{A} is an option, but it's a lot easier to read the critical edition with column footnotes, especially as I have a multi-lingual document.

Comment: so you need point 1 ?

Comment: Well I do know how to not get the line number repeated twice in the footnote for lemmas and their variants that belong to the same line: it is the \symlinenum command. My question is can I do this and also maintain a one column ledger of footnotes as seen in the example above.

Comment: I would say: you need the point 3? Actually is not possible. Or each note have a line, or the notes are paragraphed. That is the habitual way to present critical edition.

Comment: @AJMisra: What is with `\foottwocol` or even `\footthreecol`?

Comment: That is an alternative, but I'd prefer to have the critical apparatus in a single column. I just need the grouping of the footnotes to be based on line number, instead of each lemma (with variant) entry listed separately.

Comment: @AJMisra actually it s not possible. I have never seen such critical edition. In all critical edition I have seen, all the footnote are in the same paragraph, some time with separation symbol.

Comment: You should open a ticket on github, but I'am afraid to not be able to add this feature, because mixing paragraphed and not paragraphed footnote is not very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.15 of reledmac, just send on CTAN, add new feature to allow to have one footnote by one line number.

Use `Xgroupbyline` and, eventually, `Xgroupbylineseparetwolines`.